# Run Kafka with podman on multiple hosts

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, podman

Suppose I have three VMs/hosts which have `podman` installed:

- each of them runs 1 zookeeper instance as container
- each of the VMs/host run 2 kafka instances as containers (= 6).
- my notebook will make use of the cluster as Producer/Consumer
  A network/service layout I try to create:

```
  VM/host 1         VM/host 2         VM/host 3          My Dev Comp
------------      ------------       ------------       ------------
|  zoo 1   |      |  zoo 2   |       |  zoo 3   |       |   my     |
| kafka 1-2|      | kafka 3-4|       | kafka 5-6|       |  fancy   |       
|          |      |          |       |          |       | services |
------------      ------------       ------------       ------------
     |--------same-------|-------local-----|------network-----|
```

I try to run each of the container as **rootless** one, due to security restrictions. With docker of course it's easy, though you run a daemon as root, doh. I tried to understand **slirp4netns** and **containernetworking**, but I could not find an answer to my question above, because I did not understand how it works at great depth.

What's the solution to create that setup above, please, e.g. which commands are required to get this blueprint above running?

Comment: podman suppots k8s, so are you using that? If not, it's not clear how you're trying to deploy/manage against multiple hosts

Comment: Thx for response. No. I didn't use any k8s. Is that the only way to go and if yes how?

Comment: Podman doesn't offer anything like Docker Swarm to manage more than one host. Plus, even if you deployed the containers, it would not guarantee they were actually running correctly. Start here: https://strimzi.io/